# Set seed in R for Normal distribution

Tags: r, random-seed

i am doing a loop for normal distribution, skewed normal, and also skewed heavy. However, i can only manage to get the type I error for normal and skewed normal using the same set.seed. When i run the coding for skewed heavy, i get NA, and there is some missing value too in the data calculated in the coding. How can i fix this? Anyway, i already try a lot of value instead of `val`, but it did not give me the satisfaction for normal and skewed normal because i always get zero.

```
asim<-10000
pv<- rep(NA,asim)

for (val in 1:asim){
  
  set.seed(val)
  
  t=3
  n1=10
  n2=10
  n3=10
  N=n1+n2+n3
  
  data1<-rnorm(n1,0,1)
  data2<-rnorm(n2,0,1)
  data3<-rnorm(n3,0,1)
  
  # SKEWED HEAVY
  
  G=0.5
  h=0.5 # h=0 if skewed normal
  
  y1=((exp(G*data1)-1)/G)*(exp((h*data1^2)/2))
  y2=((exp(G*data2)-1)/G)*(exp((h*data2^2)/2))
  y3=((exp(G*data3)-1)/G)*(exp((h*data3^2)/2))
  
       g1=sort(y1)
  g2=sort(y2)
  g3=sort(y3)
  
  
  ybar1<-mean(g1)
  ybar2<-mean(g2)
  ybar3<-mean(g3)
  
  
  #BIWEIGHT
  
  med1=median(g1)
  med2=median(g2)
  med3=median(g3)
  
  mad=mad(c(g1,g2,g3))
  
  u1=(g1-med1)/(9*mad)
  u2=(g2-med2)/(9*mad)
  u3=(g3-med3)/(9*mad)
  
  idx1<- which(abs(u1)<1)
  idx2<- which(abs(u2)<1)
  idx3<- which(abs(u3)<1)
  
  
  #create empty list
  
  num1=c()
  num2=c()
  num3=c()
  den1=c()
  den2=c()
  den3=c()
  nume1=c()
  nume2=nume3=deno1=deno2=deno3=c()
  
  
  for(z in idx1){
    num1[z] = ((g1[z]-med1)^2)*((1-(u1[z]^2))^4)
    den1[z] = ((1-(u1[z]^2))*(1-5*(u1[z]^2)))
  }
  
  for(j in idx2){
    num2[j] = ((g2[j]-med2)^2)*((1-(u2[j]^2))^4)
    den2[j] = ((1-(u2[j]^2))*(1-5*(u2[j]^2)))
  }
  
  for(k in idx3){
    num3[k] = ((g3[k]-med3)^2)*((1-(u3[k]^2))^4)
    den3[k] = ((1-(u3[k]^2))*(1-5*(u3[k]^2)))
  }
  
  print(num1)

 }
```

after the print num1, there is NA value.

Comment: Welcome! This is not a complete example as you are asking about skewed distributions but only have the ```set.seed()``` call. I believe you know this, but the current code would have a varying seed.

Comment: oh, actually my code are so long, but let me edit and insert the code for heavy normal that i use.

Comment: It is still unclear what you want to do. The code as is will provide you different ```data1, data2, data3``` during each loop. I ran it with ```asim = 10``` and did not see any problems.

Comment: im sorry, there i already include the other coding where it started to show NA value.

Comment: The problem is ```for (z in idx1)```. You want to subset your left hand side starting at ```1``` for assignment but for some simulations, ```idx1``` starts at ```2```. R is filling ```num1[1]``` with NA_integer_.

Comment: ahhhh, i seee. how to omit the value in u1 that is not in idx1?

Comment: ```for (i in seq_along(idx1)){ z = idx1[i]; num1[i] = ...}```

Comment: did you think i can add `for(i in 1:length(idx1)` because i already sort it earlier. so the value of `u1` that is more than 1 probably be at the end of the dataset right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may want to post in code review, but the single biggest recommendation I have is to rely more heavily on `lapply` rather than sequentially named objects (e.g., `num1, num2, num3`.

I assume at the end of this, you want the results of the simulations. To do so, we will make a list using `lapply` over each simulation. I have added some of your constants outside of the loop; we need to replicate 3 datasets during each simulation. We make extensive use of `lapply` to continually make the summary statistics that you need. `Map` is similar, except it allows us to pass multiple arguments when we need it.

```r
asim<-10
t=3
n = rep(10, t)
N = sum(n)
pv<- rep(NA,asim)

lapply(seq_len(asim), function (val) {
  set.seed(val)
  
  data = lapply(n, rnorm, 0, 1)
  
  # SKEWED HEAVY
  
  G=0.5
  h=0.5 # h=0 if skewed normal
  
  y = lapply(data, function(x) ((exp(G*x)-1)/G)*(exp((h*x^2)/2)))  
  
  g = lapply(y, sort)
  ybar = lapply(y, mean)
  
  #BIWEIGHT
  
  med = lapply(g, median)
  mad_=mad(unlist(g, use.names = FALSE))
  u = Map(function (g_, med_) (g_ - med_) / (9 * mad_), g, med)
  idx = lapply(u, function(x) which(abs(x) < 1))


  num = Map(function(g_, med_, u_, idx_) (((g_ - med_) ^ 2) * ((1 - (u_^2))^4))[idx_], g, med, u, idx)
  den = Map(function(u_, idx_) ((1 - (u_^2)) * (1 - 5 * (u_ ^ 2)))[idx_], u, idx)

  data.frame(sim = rep(seq_len(t), lengths(idx)), 
             num = unlist(num, use.names = FALSE), 
             den = unlist(den, use.names = FALSE))
  }
)
```

Comment: thankyou for helping me. But, i have to complete the code based on a sample. Thus, the coding seems a bit advanced for me :))